# Create sparse matrices from given LT indices but fill with values in other list

Tags: r, list, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have three lists:

```
"corMat"     "corMatPVAL" "index"

> head(corMat)
          [,1]
[1,] 0.7786662
[2,] 0.7536617
[3,] 0.7950954
[4,] 0.7950954
[5,] 0.7950954
[6,] 0.7388970


> head(corMatPVAL)
              [,1]
[1,] 6.166382e-155
[2,] 1.304651e-139
[3,] 3.756711e-166
[4,] 3.756711e-166
[5,] 3.756711e-166
[6,] 2.097761e-131

> head(index)
     [,1]
[1,]   82
[2,]  271
[3,]  441
[4,]  442
[5,]  443
[6,]  501
```

I have to make two matrices of the size 48389 rows and  48389 columns i-e one for corMat values (1st list) filling at the indices provided in the third list (index) and one corMatPVAL (2nd list) matrix filling the same indices as mentioned in the third list (index).

Note: The indexes are of only the lower triangle of a matrix. Kindly let me know how can I make a matrix and then map these list values in the matrix form. 
the indices as mentioned in the third list. the diagonal and upper.tri portion of the matrix can be NA

Comment: `Matrix::sparseMatrix` might well be useful

Comment: @KHANirfan can you please stop revert-warring? I edited the title so it tells users more about what you want to do: create a sparse matrix from the indices and LT (lower triangular) matrix of values.

Comment: KHANirfan you already got the suggestion to use `Matrix::sparseMatrix` from @Miff, try that and if it fails post your code here and explain what's wrong. You have to install `Matrix` package, did you? It's not built-in into R. It **is** supported under 3.3.1, according to [vignette for Matrix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/vignettes/Intro2Matrix.pdf). If you had problems installing that, post a separate new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(Matrix)
sparseMatrix(index, seq_along(index), , corMat, c(48389,  48389))
sparseMatrix(index, seq_along(index), , corMatPVAL, c(48389,  48389))
```

That might be hard to visualise the output, so for a toy example:

```
sparseMatrix(10:6, 1:5, , 1:5/10,  c(10,  10))
#10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                                   
# [1,] .   .   .   .   .   . . . . .
# [2,] .   .   .   .   .   . . . . .
# [3,] .   .   .   .   .   . . . . .
# [4,] .   .   .   .   .   . . . . .
# [5,] .   .   .   .   .   . . . . .
# [6,] .   .   .   .   0.5 . . . . .
# [7,] .   .   .   0.4 .   . . . . .
# [8,] .   .   0.3 .   .   . . . . .
# [9,] .   0.2 .   .   .   . . . . .
#[10,] 0.1 .   .   .   .   . . . . .
```

Comment: Dear Guys The following worked for me
    corMat.matrix <- matrix(NA,48389,48389)
    corMat.matrix[index] <- corMat
    corMat.Pvalmatrix <- matrix(NA,48389,48389)
    corMat.Pvalmatrix[index] <- corMatPVAL
The code that Miff mentioned puts one value per column, but that was not mapping to the correct indices.